# Assigning number to .find(type) in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that allows me to select a random radio button and click on it. But on different pages I have different .find(type). Example:

Page1.html: **controlTypeToIterateOn='label'**
Page2.html: **controlTypeToIterateOn=':radio'**

```js
//Radio button
function randomNumberGenerator(max, min) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  return randomNumber;
}

function SelectRandonRadioButton(radioButtonContainer, controlTypeToIterateOn) { //Genereal function    
  var radios = $(radioButtonContainer).find(controlTypeToIterateOn);
  if (controlTypeToIterateOn == ':radio')
    controlTypeToIterateOn = 1;
  else if (controlTypeToIterateOn == 'label')
    controlTypeToIterateOn = 0;

  var randomnumber = randomNumberGenerator(radios.length - 1, 0);
  //randomizing number
  $(radios[randomnumber]).click();
  return $(radios[randomnumber]);

}

function SelectLiveRandomRadioButton(radioButtonContainer, controlTypeToIterateOn) {
  var elem = SelectRandonRadioButton(radioButtonContainer, controlTypeToIterateOn);
  $(elem).mousedown();
}

function call() {
  $(".YesNoRadio").each(function() {
    SelectLiveRandomRadioButton($(this), 1);
  });
}

call();
```

My if condition that checks the input type does not seem to work. I want to assign a numeric value that I can pass in my SelectLiveRandomRadioButton() function that's inside the call function. For example if I pass **'0'**,my **controlTypeToIterateOn = 'label'**, if I pass **1**, my **controlTypeToIterateOn = ':radio'**. Anyone who can help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here, or even what you're asking, although I'm 99% certain you can make this a lot simpler than you currently are. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: currently `controlTypeToIterateOn` is either 0 or 1 (see the function `call`), inside `SelectLiveRandomRadioButton` you test against radio or label? and your find method would be .find(1) which would never fit. Tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Rory,@axel: Forgive me for not being crystal clear. Very simply, I want a function that on '0', selects input type :radio and on '1', selects tag 'label'. When I pass this numeric value as a parameter, it should select the respective input type or label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but from looking at your code, I guess you might want to do something like this:

```
function SelectRandonRadioButton(radioButtonContainer, controlTypeToIterateOn) {
  var toFind;
  if (controlTypeToIterateOn === 1) {
    toFind = ':radio';
  } else if (controlTypeToIterateOn === 0) {
    toFind = 'label';
  }
  var hits = $(radioButtonContainer).find(toFind);
  var randomnumber = randomNumberGenerator(hits.length - 1, 0);
  $(hits[randomnumber]).click();
  return $(hits[randomnumber]);
}


function call() {
  $(".YesNoRadio").each(function() {
    // where 1 would find radio, and 0 label
    SelectLiveRandomRadioButton($(this), 1);
  });
}

call();
```